# Logging to different log file based on differnt asp.net folder using NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, web-config, nlog

I have a requirement to log to different log  file using Nlog  based  different asp.net folder

ex   if      Root/Folder1/ page.aspx--> should write to  log1.log file

```
 if     Root/Folder2/page.aspx ---> should  write to log2.log  file
```

i tried using different web.config file   for different folders   but  nlog is picking up only  Root level  config    any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you maintain namespaces in your asp.net code to match folder tree. That said, you can use wildcards in `name` (class-type namespace and name) setting for a logger. See this: http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file#Rules